# How to send AntiForgeryToken via AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I am calling `method` by AngularJs. I need to send the `AntiForgeryToken` to the `method`.

In view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
}
```

In MVC `controller`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
  ...
}
```

In AngularJs `controller`

```
this.data.Name= $('#txtNm').val();
this.data.Id = $('#Id').val();
var token = angular.element("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

$http({
method: "POST",
url: "/Students/Create",
dataType: 'json',
data: this.data,
headers: {
  '__RequestVerificationToken': token
 }
}).then(function (response) {
                //success
}, function (response) {
                //error
});
```

But, It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name="`__RequestVerificationToken`"]').val();
.....

    data: this.data,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
.....
```

Comment: @SYEDNAWAZPRINCE Sorry, diff net version, try another one

Answer (score 0):

1-CSHTML

The token are generated at the server by calling AntiForgery.GetTokens method.

```
<script>
            @functions{
        public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }


            }
    </script>

 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <input name="RequestVerificationToken" data-ng-model="RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" data-ng-init="RequestVerificationToken='@GetAntiForgeryToken()'" />
```

2-MVC Controller

When you process the request, extract the tokens from the request header. Then call the AntiForgery.Validate method to validate the tokens. The Validate method throws an exception if the tokens are not valid.

For Validate AntiForgeryToken I have used MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().

```
[HttpPost]
        [MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            // Your students create logic will be here
        }

         [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
        public class MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute
        {
            private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
            {
                string cookieToken = String.Empty;
                string formToken = String.Empty;
                string tokenValue = request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
                {
                    string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
                    if (tokens.Length == 2)
                    {
                        cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                        formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                    }
                }
                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
            }
```

3-Angular JS Controller

In http call assign in header $scope.RequestVerificationToken

```
        '__RequestVerificationToken': $scope.RequestVerificationToken
    }
```

Comment: where to put the code? in mvc `controller` or AngularJs `controller`?

Comment: Put above codes in angular js controller.

Comment: but this `function` format is not allowed in `js` file

Comment: @SYEDNAWAZPRINCE I am sorry for late response. That is my mistake I did not explain you clearly. I have edited my comments along with all required code. I hope that will work for you.

Comment: @RajshKumarSwain, thanks for your response. you used custom filter `MyValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`. but, I want to use the default one `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`.

Comment: @SYEDNAWAZPRINCE Default ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is for only if you request from cshtml view, that time default attribute will work but if you request from ajax or angular js then you have to extract the tokens from the request header and then call the AntiForgery.Validate method to validate in your controller. 

It means in your case  you are requesting from angular js so you have to write code to extract token and validate that in your controller.

Comment: In this way `Antiforgery` token can be sent. ```formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken", token);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Url,
        data: formData,
        transformRequest: angular.identity, 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });``` but the view page is reloading. so, I was finding a way to sent the `token` so than that my view page would not reload after click the button.